# Solution of the initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Find the solution of the initial value problem:

$$
2y'\cos x-y^2=2\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x
$$

Comment: the solution is given by the Mathieu-function

Comment: Setting $y=-2\cos(x)\frac{u'}{u}$ transforms this Riccati equation into a second order linear equation.

Answer (score 1):

$$2y'\cos x-y^2=2\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x$$
$$2y'\cos x-2\cos^2 x=y^2-\sin^2 x$$
$$2\cos x(y'-\cos x)=(y-\sin x)(y+\sin x)$$
$$2\cos x(y-\sin x)'=(y-\sin x)(y-\sin x+2\sin x)$$
let $y-\sin x=u$ then
$$2\cos x u'=u^2+2\sin x u$$
$$2\cos x u'-2\sin x u=u^2$$
$$2(\cos x u)'=u^2$$
$$2\dfrac{d(\cos x u)}{\cos^2x u^2}=\dfrac{dx}{\cos^2x}$$
$$-2\dfrac{1}{\cos x u}=\tan x+C$$
$$-2\dfrac{1}{\cos x (y-\sin x)}=\tan x+C$$